# Put the information in table aspx

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I have this ASPX code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;


public partial class Default4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{int i;
    public string strAdmin;
    public string strPass;
    public string strLname;
    public string strEmail;
    public string strFname;
    public string str;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dbPath = Server.MapPath(@"App_Data") + "/my_site.mdb";
        string connectionString = @"Data Source='" + dbPath + "';Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        string QueryString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(QueryString, con);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl");
        con.Close();
        strt = 
        for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            strFname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["first_name"].ToString();
            strLname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["last_name"].ToString();
            strEmail = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["user_email"].ToString();
            strPass = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["user_password"].ToString();
            strAdmin = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["is_admin"].ToString();
            str += String.Format("{0}&nbsp{1}&nbsp{2}&nbsp{3}&nbsp{4}", strFname, strLname, strEmail, strPass, strAdmin);
        }
    }
}
```

how can I                 show this info in a table so it will be more useful?
(which html tags I should add here? and where?)
I wish for help.

Comment: I'm assuming you're very new to ASP.NET.  I strongly recommend reading the entire following article, as you need a lot of basic ASP.NET knowledge before we can answer your question.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860  If you prefer video tutorials, I'd recommend http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/building-20-applications Lessons 7 and 8

Comment: thank you! You are right, i'm really new and I don't know it well, but those are  my homework for tommorow, van you help me pleas?

Comment: Check out the second link.  In particular, you should simply use a GridView and bind yyour data to it.  The videos are short and very explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

As @David mentioned you ***should*** databind to a DataGrid for this type of functionality; if however you truely wish to render that dataset to an html table (for various reasons such as styling, intense javascript etc), I use this function to return the html representation of a dataset which I then populate a div with the return html.

```
    public static string BuildHTMLTable(DataSet dataSet)
    {
        var table = dataSet.Tables[0];
        var tableString = "<table>";

        tableString += "<thead>";

        for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            tableString += "<th>" + table.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</th>";
        }
        tableString += "</thead>";
        tableString += "<tbody>";

        for(var x = 0; x < table.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            tableString += "<tr>";

            for (var y = 0; y < table.Columns.Count; y++)
            {
                tableString += "<td>";
                tableString += table.Rows[x][y];
                tableString += "</td>";
            }


            tableString += "</tr>";
        }

        tableString += "</tbody>";
        tableString += "</table>";

        return tableString;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! there is no more simple way to write the code?

Comment: @NaveTseva Not really, its just looping through the content to build the html representation.